# How to use properly UDID with push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, udid

I would like to understand how to use properly UDID with push notifications into iOS !

Recently Apple has rejected several Apps which uses UDID for tracking people.
When I read the notification guide from Apple, it seems it is not modified since one year at least. So how apple can know if we use good or bad UDID for push notifications...
Without UDID can I notify an iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need UDID for push notifications? You can get device token for push notification from `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` method.

[guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

> In APNs, assurance of accurate message routing—or token trust—is made possible through the device token. A device token is an opaque identifier of a device that APNs gives to the device when it first connects with it. The device shares the device token with its provider. Thereafter, this token accompanies each notification from the provider. It is the basis for establishing trust that the routing of a particular notification is legitimate.
>
> Note: A device token is not the same thing as the device UDID returned by the identifierForVendor or uniqueIdentifier property of UIDevice or any other similar properties such as the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager.
> The following sections discuss the requisite components for connection trust and token trust as well as the four procedures for establishing trust.